# Zebra Printer not responding outside localhost

Tags: zebra-printers, zebra

Trying to print a label from my machine using the below command

```
^XA
^FO0048,55^A@N,50,50,^FDHello-World^FS
^XZ
```

https://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&rotation=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EFO0048%2C55%5EA%40N%2C50%2C50%2C%5EFDHello-World%5EFS%0A%5EXZ

I have added Zebra printer to my printers list and choosing the same while printing with no success. The printer is not responding at all

[image]

I was able to access the printer by it's Ip address and can print a sample lable through same interface but not from my machine with command.

Below are my settings in CUPS

[image]

I'm not sure what needs to be change ? Is there any allowed list (I'm on same network), or any other settings needs to be enabled ? Please help.

Comment: use a generic text printer driver